# Bootstrap affix menu breaking on menu item click

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to integrate a right aligned menu that uses bootstrap affix and scroll-spy to fix it's position. On the whole I can get it working ok but when it scrolls to the bottom it becomes very jumpy (I have read various docs on this and can probably sort). But mainly when I am scrolled to the very bottom of the page and .affix-bottom has been assigned to the menu (all working fine) I click one of the lower links in the menu and it removes .affix-bottom and breaks the layout.

Please find a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rnewport/5sXG9/7/)

HTML here (sorry, lots but the page needs to be long to get the problem I'm getting):

```
<header></header>
<div class="cf">
<div class="container-service-menu">
                        <div id="services-menu">
                            <div class="hidden-print">
                                <ul class="nav">
                                    <li class="nav-header">Our services</li>
                                    <li><a href="#System">System auditing</a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#Risk">Risk assessments</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#Management">Management documentation</a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#ppm">Pre-planned maintenance systems</a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#Reporting">Reporting and logging programmes</a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#Tender">Tender management</a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#Contractor">Contractor selection and supervision</a> </li>

                                    <li><a href="#Design">Design validation</a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#Bacterial">Bacterial contamination management</a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#Independent">Independent water treatment advice</a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#Crisis">Crisis management</a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#Expert">Expert witness</a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#Scientific">Scientific research</a> </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<div class="content">
<h2>Our services</h2>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec sagittis metus. Suspendisse augue mi, fringilla eu mauris in, congue dignissim neque. Phasellus sed gravida eros. Quisque dictum iaculis blandit. Donec suscipit, nisi eu blandit aliquet, ligula nulla placerat leo, vel viverra turpis elit et ligula. Duis purus nisl, consectetur in metus in, consequat pulvinar libero. In lacus enim, posuere vitae mauris non, imperdiet molestie eros. Praesent egestas vestibulum dolor ut imperdiet. Cras mollis vel tellus quis viverra. Phasellus nec eros et mi pellentesque bibendum. Quisque sit amet leo tincidunt, imperdiet est eget, pellentesque eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam a feugiat eros. Integer nisi lorem, euismod aliquam iaculis in, fermentum a purus. Aenean mollis dui rutrum sagittis fermentum. Donec elementum augue at nunc malesuada, et pulvinar mi tempor.
</p>
<p>
Nullam eleifend vel mi sit amet lacinia. Etiam feugiat semper ante, egestas faucibus diam fermentum egestas. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Pellentesque eget ante eget enim volutpat imperdiet at ut odio. Integer ut accumsan tellus. Proin posuere molestie mi, ut tempor lacus tincidunt in. Phasellus adipiscing tellus sed libero porta, quis pellentesque augue vehicula. Aenean euismod elit a tellus porta pulvinar eu non nisi. Proin nec luctus dui. Ut congue a nisi non scelerisque. Aliquam at congue nunc. Curabitur nisl lorem, fermentum at lobortis et, scelerisque quis mi. Vivamus porttitor sagittis urna, in auctor felis bibendum sed. Donec ultricies turpis et ligula pretium pretium. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</p>
<p>
Mauris viverra commodo accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Donec vitae metus faucibus, commodo velit ornare, sodales leo. Mauris non congue urna, ut elementum sapien. Proin iaculis metus non lacinia consequat. Fusce dignissim gravida augue, vel rhoncus massa lobortis ut. Quisque quis arcu fermentum ligula viverra dapibus.
</p>
<h3 id="System" class="section-header">System auditing</h3>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec sagittis metus. Suspendisse augue mi, fringilla eu mauris in, congue dignissim neque. Phasellus sed gravida eros. Quisque dictum iaculis blandit. Donec suscipit, nisi eu blandit aliquet, ligula nulla placerat leo, vel viverra turpis elit et ligula. Duis purus nisl, consectetur in metus in, consequat pulvinar libero. In lacus enim, posuere vitae mauris non, imperdiet molestie eros. Praesent egestas vestibulum dolor ut imperdiet. Cras mollis vel tellus quis viverra. Phasellus nec eros et mi pellentesque bibendum. Quisque sit amet leo tincidunt, imperdiet est eget, pellentesque eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam a feugiat eros. Integer nisi lorem, euismod aliquam iaculis in, fermentum a purus. Aenean mollis dui rutrum sagittis fermentum. Donec elementum augue at nunc malesuada, et pulvinar mi tempor.
</p>
<p>
Nullam eleifend vel mi sit amet lacinia. Etiam feugiat semper ante, egestas faucibus diam fermentum egestas. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Pellentesque eget ante eget enim volutpat imperdiet at ut odio. Integer ut accumsan tellus. Proin posuere molestie mi, ut tempor lacus tincidunt in. Phasellus adipiscing tellus sed libero porta, quis pellentesque augue vehicula. Aenean euismod elit a tellus porta pulvinar eu non nisi. Proin nec luctus dui. Ut congue a nisi non scelerisque. Aliquam at congue nunc. Curabitur nisl lorem, fermentum at lobortis et, scelerisque quis mi. Vivamus porttitor sagittis urna, in auctor felis bibendum sed. Donec ultricies turpis et ligula pretium pretium. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</p>
<p>
Mauris viverra commodo accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Donec vitae metus faucibus, commodo velit ornare, sodales leo. Mauris non congue urna, ut elementum sapien. Proin iaculis metus non lacinia consequat. Fusce dignissim gravida augue, vel rhoncus massa lobortis ut. Quisque quis arcu fermentum ligula viverra dapibus.
</p>

<h3 id="Risk" class="section-header">Risk assessments</h3>
    <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec sagittis metus. Suspendisse augue mi, fringilla eu mauris in, congue dignissim neque. Phasellus sed gravida eros. Quisque dictum iaculis blandit. Donec suscipit, nisi eu blandit aliquet, ligula nulla placerat leo, vel viverra turpis elit et ligula. Duis purus nisl, consectetur in metus in, consequat pulvinar libero. In lacus enim, posuere vitae mauris non, imperdiet molestie eros. Praesent egestas vestibulum dolor ut imperdiet. Cras mollis vel tellus quis viverra. Phasellus nec eros et mi pellentesque bibendum. Quisque sit amet leo tincidunt, imperdiet est eget, pellentesque eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam a feugiat eros. Integer nisi lorem, euismod aliquam iaculis in, fermentum a purus. Aenean mollis dui rutrum sagittis fermentum. Donec elementum augue at nunc malesuada, et pulvinar mi tempor.
</p>
<p>
Nullam eleifend vel mi sit amet lacinia. Etiam feugiat semper ante, egestas faucibus diam fermentum egestas. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Pellentesque eget ante eget enim volutpat imperdiet at ut odio. Integer ut accumsan tellus. Proin posuere molestie mi, ut tempor lacus tincidunt in. Phasellus adipiscing tellus sed libero porta, quis pellentesque augue vehicula. Aenean euismod elit a tellus porta pulvinar eu non nisi. Proin nec luctus dui. Ut congue a nisi non scelerisque. Aliquam at congue nunc. Curabitur nisl lorem, fermentum at lobortis et, scelerisque quis mi. Vivamus porttitor sagittis urna, in auctor felis bibendum sed. Donec ultricies turpis et ligula pretium pretium. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</p>
<p>
Mauris viverra commodo accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Donec vitae metus faucibus, commodo velit ornare, sodales leo. Mauris non congue urna, ut elementum sapien. Proin iaculis metus non lacinia consequat. Fusce dignissim gravida augue, vel rhoncus massa lobortis ut. Quisque quis arcu fermentum ligula viverra dapibus.
</p>

<h3 id="Management" class="section-header">Management documentation</h3><p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec sagittis metus. Suspendisse augue mi, fringilla eu mauris in, congue dignissim neque. Phasellus sed gravida eros. Quisque dictum iaculis blandit. Donec suscipit, nisi eu blandit aliquet, ligula nulla placerat leo, vel viverra turpis elit et ligula. Duis purus nisl, consectetur in metus in, consequat pulvinar libero. In lacus enim, posuere vitae mauris non, imperdiet molestie eros. Praesent egestas vestibulum dolor ut imperdiet. Cras mollis vel tellus quis viverra. Phasellus nec eros et mi pellentesque bibendum. Quisque sit amet leo tincidunt, imperdiet est eget, pellentesque eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam a feugiat eros. Integer nisi lorem, euismod aliquam iaculis in, fermentum a purus. Aenean mollis dui rutrum sagittis fermentum. Donec elementum augue at nunc malesuada, et pulvinar mi tempor.
</p>
<p>
Nullam eleifend vel mi sit amet lacinia. Etiam feugiat semper ante, egestas faucibus diam fermentum egestas. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Pellentesque eget ante eget enim volutpat imperdiet at ut odio. Integer ut accumsan tellus. Proin posuere molestie mi, ut tempor lacus tincidunt in. Phasellus adipiscing tellus sed libero porta, quis pellentesque augue vehicula. Aenean euismod elit a tellus porta pulvinar eu non nisi. Proin nec luctus dui. Ut congue a nisi non scelerisque. Aliquam at congue nunc. Curabitur nisl lorem, fermentum at lobortis et, scelerisque quis mi. Vivamus porttitor sagittis urna, in auctor felis bibendum sed. Donec ultricies turpis et ligula pretium pretium. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</p>
<p>
Mauris viverra commodo accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Donec vitae metus faucibus, commodo velit ornare, sodales leo. Mauris non congue urna, ut elementum sapien. Proin iaculis metus non lacinia consequat. Fusce dignissim gravida augue, vel rhoncus massa lobortis ut. Quisque quis arcu fermentum ligula viverra dapibus.
</p>

<h3 id="ppm" class="section-header">Pre-planned maintenance systems</h3><p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec sagittis metus. Suspendisse augue mi, fringilla eu mauris in, congue dignissim neque. Phasellus sed gravida eros. Quisque dictum iaculis blandit. Donec suscipit, nisi eu blandit aliquet, ligula nulla placerat leo, vel viverra turpis elit et ligula. Duis purus nisl, consectetur in metus in, consequat pulvinar libero. In lacus enim, posuere vitae mauris non, imperdiet molestie eros. Praesent egestas vestibulum dolor ut imperdiet. Cras mollis vel tellus quis viverra. Phasellus nec eros et mi pellentesque bibendum. Quisque sit amet leo tincidunt, imperdiet est eget, pellentesque eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam a feugiat eros. Integer nisi lorem, euismod aliquam iaculis in, fermentum a purus. Aenean mollis dui rutrum sagittis fermentum. Donec elementum augue at nunc malesuada, et pulvinar mi tempor.
</p>
<p>
Nullam eleifend vel mi sit amet lacinia. Etiam feugiat semper ante, egestas faucibus diam fermentum egestas. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Pellentesque eget ante eget enim volutpat imperdiet at ut odio. Integer ut accumsan tellus. Proin posuere molestie mi, ut tempor lacus tincidunt in. Phasellus adipiscing tellus sed libero porta, quis pellentesque augue vehicula. Aenean euismod elit a tellus porta pulvinar eu non nisi. Proin nec luctus dui. Ut congue a nisi non scelerisque. Aliquam at congue nunc. Curabitur nisl lorem, fermentum at lobortis et, scelerisque quis mi. Vivamus porttitor sagittis urna, in auctor felis bibendum sed. Donec ultricies turpis et ligula pretium pretium. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</p>
<p>
Mauris viverra commodo accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Donec vitae metus faucibus, commodo velit ornare, sodales leo. Mauris non congue urna, ut elementum sapien. Proin iaculis metus non lacinia consequat. Fusce dignissim gravida augue, vel rhoncus massa lobortis ut. Quisque quis arcu fermentum ligula viverra dapibus.
</p>

<h3 id="Reporting" class="section-header">Reporting and logging programmes</h3><p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec sagittis metus. Suspendisse augue mi, fringilla eu mauris in, congue dignissim neque. Phasellus sed gravida eros. Quisque dictum iaculis blandit. Donec suscipit, nisi eu blandit aliquet, ligula nulla placerat leo, vel viverra turpis elit et ligula. Duis purus nisl, consectetur in metus in, consequat pulvinar libero. In lacus enim, posuere vitae mauris non, imperdiet molestie eros. Praesent egestas vestibulum dolor ut imperdiet. Cras mollis vel tellus quis viverra. Phasellus nec eros et mi pellentesque bibendum. Quisque sit amet leo tincidunt, imperdiet est eget, pellentesque eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam a feugiat eros. Integer nisi lorem, euismod aliquam iaculis in, fermentum a purus. Aenean mollis dui rutrum sagittis fermentum. Donec elementum augue at nunc malesuada, et pulvinar mi tempor.
</p>
<p>
Nullam eleifend vel mi sit amet lacinia. Etiam feugiat semper ante, egestas faucibus diam fermentum egestas. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Pellentesque eget ante eget enim volutpat imperdiet at ut odio. Integer ut accumsan tellus. Proin posuere molestie mi, ut tempor lacus tincidunt in. Phasellus adipiscing tellus sed libero porta, quis pellentesque augue vehicula. Aenean euismod elit a tellus porta pulvinar eu non nisi. Proin nec luctus dui. Ut congue a nisi non scelerisque. Aliquam at congue nunc. Curabitur nisl lorem, fermentum at lobortis et, scelerisque quis mi. Vivamus porttitor sagittis urna, in auctor felis bibendum sed. Donec ultricies turpis et ligula pretium pretium. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</p>
<p>
Mauris viverra commodo accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Donec vitae metus faucibus, commodo velit ornare, sodales leo. Mauris non congue urna, ut elementum sapien. Proin iaculis metus non lacinia consequat. Fusce dignissim gravida augue, vel rhoncus massa lobortis ut. Quisque quis arcu fermentum ligula viverra dapibus.
</p>

<h3 id="Tender" class="section-header">Tender management</h3>
    <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec sagittis metus. Suspendisse augue mi, fringilla eu mauris in, congue dignissim neque. Phasellus sed gravida eros. Quisque dictum iaculis blandit. Donec suscipit, nisi eu blandit aliquet, ligula nulla placerat leo, vel viverra turpis elit et ligula. Duis purus nisl, consectetur in metus in, consequat pulvinar libero. In lacus enim, posuere vitae mauris non, imperdiet molestie eros. Praesent egestas vestibulum dolor ut imperdiet. Cras mollis vel tellus quis viverra. Phasellus nec eros et mi pellentesque bibendum. Quisque sit amet leo tincidunt, imperdiet est eget, pellentesque eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam a feugiat eros. Integer nisi lorem, euismod aliquam iaculis in, fermentum a purus. Aenean mollis dui rutrum sagittis fermentum. Donec elementum augue at nunc malesuada, et pulvinar mi tempor.
</p>

<h3 id="Contractor" class="section-header">Contractor selection and supervision</h3><p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec sagittis metus. Suspendisse augue mi, fringilla eu mauris in, congue dignissim neque. Phasellus sed gravida eros. Quisque dictum iaculis blandit. Donec suscipit, nisi eu blandit aliquet, ligula nulla placerat leo, vel viverra turpis elit et ligula. Duis purus nisl, consectetur in metus in, consequat pulvinar libero. In lacus enim, posuere vitae mauris non, imperdiet molestie eros. Praesent egestas vestibulum dolor ut imperdiet. Cras mollis vel tellus quis viverra. Phasellus nec eros et mi pellentesque bibendum. Quisque sit amet leo tincidunt, imperdiet est eget, pellentesque eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam a feugiat eros. Integer nisi lorem, euismod aliquam iaculis in, fermentum a purus. Aenean mollis dui rutrum sagittis fermentum. Donec elementum augue at nunc malesuada, et pulvinar mi tempor.
</p>
<p>
Nullam eleifend vel mi sit amet lacinia. Etiam feugiat semper ante, egestas faucibus diam fermentum egestas. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Pellentesque eget ante eget enim volutpat imperdiet at ut odio. Integer ut accumsan tellus. Proin posuere molestie mi, ut tempor lacus tincidunt in. Phasellus adipiscing tellus sed libero porta, quis pellentesque augue vehicula. Aenean euismod elit a tellus porta pulvinar eu non nisi. Proin nec luctus dui. Ut congue a nisi non scelerisque. Aliquam at congue nunc. Curabitur nisl lorem, fermentum at lobortis et, scelerisque quis mi. Vivamus porttitor sagittis urna, in auctor felis bibendum sed. Donec ultricies turpis et ligula pretium pretium. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</p>
<p>
Mauris viverra commodo accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Donec vitae metus faucibus, commodo velit ornare, sodales leo. Mauris non congue urna, ut elementum sapien. Proin iaculis metus non lacinia consequat. Fusce dignissim gravida augue, vel rhoncus massa lobortis ut. Quisque quis arcu fermentum ligula viverra dapibus.
</p>
<h3 id="Design" class="section-header">Design validation</h3>
    <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec sagittis metus. Suspendisse augue mi, fringilla eu mauris in, congue dignissim neque. Phasellus sed gravida eros. Quisque dictum iaculis blandit. Donec suscipit, nisi eu blandit aliquet, ligula nulla placerat leo, vel viverra turpis elit et ligula. Duis purus nisl, consectetur in metus in, consequat pulvinar libero. In lacus enim, posuere vitae mauris non, imperdiet molestie eros. Praesent egestas vestibulum dolor ut imperdiet. Cras mollis vel tellus quis viverra. Phasellus nec eros et mi pellentesque bibendum. Quisque sit amet leo tincidunt, imperdiet est eget, pellentesque eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam a feugiat eros. Integer nisi lorem, euismod aliquam iaculis in, fermentum a purus. Aenean mollis dui rutrum sagittis fermentum. Donec elementum augue at nunc malesuada, et pulvinar mi tempor.
</p>
<p>
Nullam eleifend vel mi sit amet lacinia. Etiam feugiat semper ante, egestas faucibus diam fermentum egestas. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Pellentesque eget ante eget enim volutpat imperdiet at ut odio. Integer ut accumsan tellus. Proin posuere molestie mi, ut tempor lacus tincidunt in. Phasellus adipiscing tellus sed libero porta, quis pellentesque augue vehicula. Aenean euismod elit a tellus porta pulvinar eu non nisi. Proin nec luctus dui. Ut congue a nisi non scelerisque. Aliquam at congue nunc. Curabitur nisl lorem, fermentum at lobortis et, scelerisque quis mi. Vivamus porttitor sagittis urna, in auctor felis bibendum sed. Donec ultricies turpis et ligula pretium pretium. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</p>
<p>
Mauris viverra commodo accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Donec vitae metus faucibus, commodo velit ornare, sodales leo. Mauris non congue urna, ut elementum sapien. Proin iaculis metus non lacinia consequat. Fusce dignissim gravida augue, vel rhoncus massa lobortis ut. Quisque quis arcu fermentum ligula viverra dapibus.
</p>

<h3 id="Bacterial" class="section-header">Bacterial contamination management</h3>
    <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec sagittis metus. Suspendisse augue mi, fringilla eu mauris in, congue dignissim neque. Phasellus sed gravida eros. Quisque dictum iaculis blandit. Donec suscipit, nisi eu blandit aliquet, ligula nulla placerat leo, vel viverra turpis elit et ligula. Duis purus nisl, consectetur in metus in, consequat pulvinar libero. In lacus enim, posuere vitae mauris non, imperdiet molestie eros. Praesent egestas vestibulum dolor ut imperdiet. Cras mollis vel tellus quis viverra. Phasellus nec eros et mi pellentesque bibendum. Quisque sit amet leo tincidunt, imperdiet est eget, pellentesque eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam a feugiat eros. Integer nisi lorem, euismod aliquam iaculis in, fermentum a purus. Aenean mollis dui rutrum sagittis fermentum. Donec elementum augue at nunc malesuada, et pulvinar mi tempor.
</p>
<p>
Nullam eleifend vel mi sit amet lacinia. Etiam feugiat semper ante, egestas faucibus diam fermentum egestas. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Pellentesque eget ante eget enim volutpat imperdiet at ut odio. Integer ut accumsan tellus. Proin posuere molestie mi, ut tempor lacus tincidunt in. Phasellus adipiscing tellus sed libero porta, quis pellentesque augue vehicula. Aenean euismod elit a tellus porta pulvinar eu non nisi. Proin nec luctus dui. Ut congue a nisi non scelerisque. Aliquam at congue nunc. Curabitur nisl lorem, fermentum at lobortis et, scelerisque quis mi. Vivamus porttitor sagittis urna, in auctor felis bibendum sed. Donec ultricies turpis et ligula pretium pretium. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</p>
<p>
Mauris viverra commodo accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Donec vitae metus faucibus, commodo velit ornare, sodales leo. Mauris non congue urna, ut elementum sapien. Proin iaculis metus non lacinia consequat. Fusce dignissim gravida augue, vel rhoncus massa lobortis ut. Quisque quis arcu fermentum ligula viverra dapibus.
</p>

<h3 id="Independent" class="section-header">Independent water treatment advice</h3>
    <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec nec sagittis metus. Suspendisse augue mi, fringilla eu mauris in, congue dignissim neque. Phasellus sed gravida eros. Quisque dictum iaculis blandit. Donec suscipit, nisi eu blandit aliquet, ligula nulla placerat leo, vel viverra turpis elit et ligula. Duis purus nisl, consectetur in metus in, consequat pulvinar libero. In lacus enim, posuere vitae mauris non, imperdiet molestie eros. Praesent egestas vestibulum dolor ut imperdiet. Cras mollis vel tellus quis viverra. Phasellus nec eros et mi pellentesque bibendum. Quisque sit amet leo tincidunt, imperdiet est eget, pellentesque eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam a feugiat eros. Integer nisi lorem, euismod aliquam iaculis in, fermentum a purus. Aenean mollis dui rutrum sagittis fermentum. Donec elementum augue at nunc malesuada, et pulvinar mi tempor.
</p>
<p>
Nullam eleifend vel mi sit amet lacinia. Etiam feugiat semper ante, egestas faucibus diam fermentum egestas. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Pellentesque eget ante eget enim volutpat imperdiet at ut odio. Integer ut accumsan tellus. Proin posuere molestie mi, ut tempor lacus tincidunt in. Phasellus adipiscing tellus sed libero porta, quis pellentesque augue vehicula. Aenean euismod elit a tellus porta pulvinar eu non nisi. Proin nec luctus dui. Ut congue a nisi non scelerisque. Aliquam at congue nunc. Curabitur nisl lorem, fermentum at lobortis et, scelerisque quis mi. Vivamus porttitor sagittis urna, in auctor felis bibendum sed. Donec ultricies turpis et ligula pretium pretium. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</p>
<p>
Mauris viverra commodo accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Donec vitae metus faucibus, commodo velit ornare, sodales leo. Mauris non congue urna, ut elementum sapien. Proin iaculis metus non lacinia consequat. Fusce dignissim gravida augue, vel rhoncus massa lobortis ut. Quisque quis arcu fermentum ligula viverra dapibus.
</p>

<h3 id="Crisis" class="section-header">Crisis management</h3>

<p>
Mauris viverra commodo accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Donec vitae metus faucibus, commodo velit ornare, sodales leo. Mauris non congue urna, ut elementum sapien. Proin iaculis metus non lacinia consequat. Fusce dignissim gravida augue, vel rhoncus massa lobortis ut. Quisque quis arcu fermentum ligula viverra dapibus.
</p>

<h3 id="Expert" class="section-header">Expert witness</h3>

<p>
Mauris viverra commodo accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Donec vitae metus faucibus, commodo velit ornare, sodales leo. Mauris non congue urna, ut elementum sapien. Proin iaculis metus non lacinia consequat. Fusce dignissim gravida augue, vel rhoncus massa lobortis ut. Quisque quis arcu fermentum ligula viverra dapibus.
</p> <h3 id="Scientific" class="section-header">Scientific research</h3>
    <p>
Mauris viverra commodo accumsan. Suspendisse potenti. Donec vitae metus faucibus, commodo velit ornare, sodales leo. Mauris non congue urna, ut elementum sapien. Proin iaculis metus non lacinia consequat. Fusce dignissim gravida augue, vel rhoncus massa lobortis ut. Quisque quis arcu fermentum ligula viverra dapibus.
</p>

    </div>
                </div>
    <footer></footer>
```

CSS here:

```
header {
    height: 180px;
    width: 100%;
    background: grey;
}

footer {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background: grey;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}

.content {
    float: left;
    margin:0;
    width: 70%;
    position: relative;
}
.container-service-menu {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: inherit;
}

#services-menu {
    }

#services-menu .nav li a {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

#services-menu.affix-top {
    top:27px; 
    }

#services-menu.affix {
    top:30px;
    position: fixed!important;
    width: inherit;
    }

#services-menu.affix-bottom {
    width: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    /*top: auto!important;*/
    bottom: 350px;  /*height of the footer*/
    }

#services-menu div ul li.active {
    background: #0099D8;
    color: #fff;
    border-left: 3px solid grey;
    }

#services-menu div ul li.active a:hover {
    background: #0099D8;
    cursor:default;
    }

#services-menu div ul li.active a {
    color: #fff;
    }

#services-menu div ul li.nav-header {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: #EFEFEF;
    /* color: #fff; */
    /* font-weight: bold; */
    border-bottom: 3px solid #0099D8;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }
```

And JS here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#services-menu').affix({
                offset: {
                    top: 190,
                    bottom: 350
                }
            });
            $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#services-menu' })
        });
```

Thanks in advance and I'm fairly new here so please inform me of any faux pas...

Answer (score 0):

Why not change:

```
offset: { 
    top: 190, 
    bottom: 350 
}
```

To:

```
offset: { 
    top: 190
}
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5sXG9/8/)

Also note that as you have longer menu items, the selection class (when they are scrolled to) causes their width to exceed the number of lines they occupy so they may 'jump' onto a second line. You can either change the menu width, the text length or the underlying CSS to counteract this.

Comment: Thanks SW4.  It's the bottom offset that I'm trying to get working, I think with your code it removes the functionality completely?  My problem is that the site I'm working on has a tall footer and a long menu and they are at odds with each other. I could reduce padding/margins on all the menu items but don't really want to mess with the design of the menu too much.  I had noticed the width issue you referred to but it's not doing that on my actual site, so not a major concern.  Thanks again